# Adding the results of a separate query to a JSON encoded array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I've got a query to my MySQL database returning four fields of information from a MySQL table (information), which I then encode for JSON using PHP's `json_encode()` function. Two of the fields it returns are "staffMember" and "lineManager", which return integers that relate to the ID of that person in a (separate) users table.

My query returns the following (in table format):

```
id is 1
staffMember is 14
lineManager is 12
description is this is a description
```

etc.. for all the rows.

14 (in the case of the above for example) refers to a row in the users table that would be something like:

```
id is 14
firstname is dave
secondname is jones
```

My question is therefore, how can I get the JSON part of the query to return "dave jones" instead of 14? As the info isn't held in the same table in MySQL.

Comment: Make changes to your query (a join of some sort probably). Could you post it here so we can help you with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN in your database request like

```
SELECT a.id, CONCAT(b.firstname, ' ', b.secondname) AS staffMember, a.lineManager, a.description 
  FROM a 
  LEFT JOIN b ON (a.staffMember = b.id)
```

where a and b - your table names

Comment: If i wanted to extend this to repeat the same process at the same time for the linemanager integer too (which references the same users table) is that achievable? I understand you can't have two left joins to the same table but different fields.. perhaps some kind of Union query? it's a bit beyond me, but i'd be very grateful for any help you could provide..

Comment: You could use two left joins, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters mentioned, you will definitely want to add the firstname and lastname fields to your SQL result set. You can do this by altering your query to JOIN to the table that houses your firstname and lastname data. The "ON" clause of your join would be the id common to both tables. An example would be:

```
SELECT * FROM yourdb.table1 T1 LEFT JOIN yourdb.table2 T2 ON T1.staffMember = T2.id;
```